# How to overlap two images?

Tags: java, image, user-interface, png, buffered

I try to make one overlapped .png image from two another .png images which I read and buffered, so what is the easiest way to get overlapped image of both ones?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `BufferedImage` based on the sizes of the two images
2. Get the `Graphics` object from the `BufferedImage`
3. Paint each image onto the `BufferedImage` using the `drawImage(...)` method of the `Graphics` object.